# передача файлов между сервером и клиентом Java

Tags: java, xml, post, клиент-сервер

Есть объект с некоторым количеством текстовых полей и ассоциированный с ним файл. Необходимо реализовать передачу этих данных от клиента серверу. Сервер изменяет часть полей, и, возможно, файл, и отправляет данные обратно клиенту. Отправка данных должна реализовываться через метод HTTP POST.
Если я правильно понял, можно упаковать всё это в xml-файл (можно ли кроме текстовых полей добавить в xml ассоциированный файл?). Какую библиотеку актуально сейчас использовать для работы с xml в Java? 
Как отправить этот xml файл на сервер и получить измененный xml файл в ответ? Реализация должна быть на Java, и клиента, и сервера. Был бы очень признателен за названия библиотек, которыми можно воспользоваться для решения этой задачи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отправить http Post-сообщение можно средствами Java SE.

C XML также можно работать средствами Java SE (The Java API for XML Processing (JAXP)): SAX, DOM, StAX.
Выбор технологий очень зависит о задачи и планов дальнейшего развития приложения.

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите отправлять через xml, то вам нужно использовать архитектуру RESTful. Данная архитектура это комплекс решений, связанных с передачей информации о ресурсе с клиента на сервер, а также наоборот. Ресурсы REST могут быть представлены практически в любой форме например: XML, JSON и даже HTML. Архитектура предусматривает организацию передачи ресурса из одного приложения в другое. Советую обратиться к Spring MVC. Он использует очень гибкую модель создания классов контроллеров.